# How can I improve the power consumption of the open source AMD graphics drivers?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, power-management, ati

How i can optimize the power consumption of the open source radeon driver?
I don't want to use official amd driver cause of an error with sleep mode.

AMD E-450 cpu\gpu.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal, and copy the following

```
echo dynpm|sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
```

If you do not like it, you can return back by using

```
echo profile|sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
```

If you want to set at boot, type

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add before "**exit 0**"

```
echo dynpm > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
```

***This may reduce the performance***